# Google translate in webpage using the python

Tags: python, excel, google-chrome, firefox, automation

Can we do the following in python, I wanted to avoid the manual work of translation.

- open Google translate
- open the excel sheet, copy 50 English strings and paste in Google translate
- Convert to other language and put in excel and again copy next 50 strings and continue

Note:- I have tried translate API it has the limitations of 30K strings.

Comment: It is possible to invoke the google translate API in a python script https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/. You could then parse the excel file and translate individual lines.

Comment: why the firefox and chrome tags?

Comment: Maybe you could use selenium?

Comment: Because I will use Chrome/Firefox linking for  translation

Comment: @user11650863 read this: https://pypi.org/project/selenium/

Comment: Even if you do use selenium, I’m pretty sure google starts hitting you with captcha requests after 400-500 translations (that’s what happened for me at least)

Comment: So is it not achievable? How did you overcome it?